# break and return most recent value from recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to confirm that the input is a single alphabetical letter. Is there a way to return the first valid value and then end the recursion before it outputs previous invalid entries.

For example, if the first entry is '4', second entry is '$', and third entry is 'a', I would like to only return 'a' and not '4' and '$'.

```
def check_guess(guess):
    guess = str(guess)
    if guess.isalpha() == True and len(guess) == 1:
        return guess    
    else:
        guess = raw_input("No special or multiple characters allowed. Reenter guess: ").lower()
        check_guess(guess)  #recursion
```

(this is for a simple game but was looking to get a better understanding of recursion more than an alternative way to code this)

Comment: This is not a good use for recursion. Don't try to learn how to use recursion by shoe-horning it into places it doesn't belong. Try writing a tree search or something, where recursion might be a good idea!

Comment: Anyway, I think the answer you're looking for is `return check_guess(guess)  #recursion`

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a tempting but poor way to handle user input. Use a loop instead:

```
def get_guess():
    while 1:
        guess = raw_input("Guess? ")
        if guess.isalpha() and len(guess) == 1:
            return guess
        print "Guess must be a single letter."
```